# ClassCastException: datastructures.instances.JClass cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, class, caching, classcastexception, jcs

I know there are quite a few CCE questions on SO.  I have read the majority of them either in detail or briefly and I cannot find anything that applies to my situation.  My exact error is:

`Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: datastructures.instances.JClass cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList` at `if ((results = mCallsDownstreamCache.get(origin)) == null) {`

As you will see in the code, what I'm doing is asking for an `ArrayList` from a cache (`HashMap`) and then making a decision on that.  The odd behavior here is that `datastructures.instances.JClass` is in **no way** referenced in the piece of code that generates the error.

To give you some context, I have a database "model" which fulfills requests from a "controller".  Those results are stored in a cache local to the model and if they exist the model will return the cache thus not having to hit the db.  My caching elements are effectively decorators for the [Commons' JCS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/).

The offending line is wrapped in a `block comment` and `inline comment`

```
public class AnalyzeModel extends Model {

    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    public CacheDecorator<Integer, JClass> mClassCache = new CacheDecorator<Integer, JClass>();
    public CacheDecorator<Integer, JMethod> mMethodCache = new CacheDecorator<Integer, JMethod>();
    public CacheDecorator<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> mCallsUpstreamCache =
            new CacheDecorator<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    public CacheDecorator<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> mCallsDownstreamCache =
            new CacheDecorator<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

    public void close() {
        super.close();
    }

    public Pair<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> selectCallGraphDownstream(int origin) {
        ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        /**
         * This is the offending line
         */
        if ((results = mCallsDownstreamCache.get(origin)) == null) {
        // End error line
            results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (Record r : mQuery.select(
                    mQuery.mQuerier.select(Calls.CALLS.TID)
                            .from(Calls.CALLS)
                            .where(Calls.CALLS.SID.eq(origin)))) {
                results.add(r.getValue(Calls.CALLS.TID));
            }
            mCallsDownstreamCache.put(origin, results);
            Statistics.CACHE_MISS++;
        } else {
            Statistics.CACHE_HITS++;
        }
        return new Pair<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(origin, results);
    }

}

public class CacheDecorator<K, V> {

    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private CacheAccess<K, V> mCache;

    public CacheDecorator() {
        try {
            mCache = JCS.getInstance("default");
        } catch (CacheException e) {
            BillBoard.e(TAG, "Error getting cache configuration: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get an object from cache
     * @param obj object to retrieve from cache
     * @return generic object of retrieved value, null if not found
     */
    public V get(K obj) {
        return mCache.get(obj);
    }

    /**
     * Place an object in cache
     * @param key generic key for reference
     * @param obj generic object to be cached
     */
    public synchronized void put(K key, V obj) {
        try {
            if(obj != null) {
                mCache.putSafe(key, obj);
            }
        } catch( CacheException e) {
            //BillBoard.d(TAG, obj.toString());
            //BillBoard.e(TAG, "Error placing item in cache: " + e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the stats from our cache manager
     * @return String of our cache object
     */
    public String getStats() {
        shutDownCache();
        return mCache.getStats();
    }

    public static void shutDownCache() {
        CompositeCacheManager.getInstance().shutDown();
    }
}
```

Some additional details that may, or may not, be helpful:

- The `Pair<V, K>` datastructure is just an immutable 2-pair tuple class
- `CacheDecorator.get(V obj)` returns `null` if the object doesn't exist in cache
- I've tried quite a bit in regards to casting and such
- `JClass` does have references elsewhere in the code, but no reference in the offending method
- `JClass` is a representation of a java class, it's a custom structure

Comment: What is the method signature of `CachDecorator.get(int)`?  Specifically, what is that method's return type?

Comment: I added the class definition of `CacheDecorator`

Comment: Could you also add the implementation of the `JCS.getInstance` method? It looks like you're using a singleton, but how is that default instance created, and with which data types?

Comment: I cannot, that is part of the JCS from commons.  There might be a javadoc on that, but it is their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By altering your config to include region-specific configs as presented in the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/RegionProperties.html), and passing a region to your wrapper, should resolve the problem.

Looks like you are using the same cache region for all your wrappers and hence referencing the same 'under laying cache' across your wrappers. Could you change `mCache = JCS.getInstance("default");` to something like `mCache = JCS.getInstance("uniqueNameForWrapper");` for all your wrappers?

Comment: The string passed to the instance is strictly for parsing the properties config that is required for the JCS instance.  So all `CacheAccess` instances will use the caching strategies defined in `default` sections of the config.

Comment: I was looking at the source for JCS.getInstance  at [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/commons-jcs-core/apidocs/index.html) **line 162**, following the trail you end up at [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/commons-jcs-core/apidocs/index.html) **line 591**, I am not familiar with JCS and I could be wrong but it looks like that name is used as a key for the underlaying CacheAccess object

Comment: hmm, that could be a lead to the answer.  I think the answer might actually in the use of `defineRegion` [defined](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/commons-jcs-core/apidocs/index.html).  My decorator might be too simple.  I'll do some testing.  From what I've read [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/getting_started/intro.html) the `JCS.getInstance([name])` refers to the  properties file that is required to define a cache.  You can see I trivially decorated their simple example as a generalized interface.

Comment: Yes i saw that one,and I suspect each region definition maps to exactly one 'CacheAccess' object. By the way another way you can use the configuration file to define the custom regions like in [here](http://www.devx.com/Java/introduction-to-java-caching-system.html)

Comment: By the way another way you can define the custom regions is by using the configuration file  like  [here](http://www.devx.com/Java/introduction-to-java-caching-system.html). So the way I see it;Each wrapper should have its own corresponding region.One question though,did you try what I suggested?i wouldn't be surprised if it still worked

Comment: I'm working on implementing it now.  The only argument for why this approach won't work is because I do this very same thing in other models (multiple caches in the same class using the same instance) and it all works perfectly there.

Comment: any additional information on this?  I have a similar scenario in an older version of JCS.  We are only using a single region across various instances, but using unique keys (and have verified they are truly unique).  There are odd times where we should get object A back but are getting object B back instead so trying to see if this solution would apply.  Unable to reproduce it in a test case as of yet which is making it hard to determine how to fix.